# TableView in Detail view has whitespace above prototype cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, storyboard

I have a master detail project I just created, and I added a tableView to my DetailViewController and and then added a Prototype Cell. There is whitespace above the cells in the tableView that shows both in the storyboard and on the phone when I run it. The cells load fine, and the data populates, but I can't get the whitespace to go away. Is this a bug in Xcode or something?

Storyboard:
[image]

Phone:
[image]

That is not part of the cell, as the red background on my custom cell indicates.

It is not there if I remove my cell from storyboard, as in the whole tableView appears the standard empty gray color.

How can I remove it?

EDIT: My tableView is Plain, not Grouped. I am using the latest Xcode.

Comment: try with `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false`

Comment: That was it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is under the assumption that the backgroundColor of your view in the ViewController is white, in which case you may have initialized your tableView with a style of **.Grouped**. I am am able to replicate this in the simulator, and setting the style to **.Plain** fixes the issue

Please see Apple's Documentation for the the styles found here.
[UITableView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UITableViewStyle)

Also double check that edgesForExtendedLayout is set to false on the detail view controller.

Comment: My tableView is plane not grouped.

Comment: What are the settings on the viewController for edgesForExtendedLayout and automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets ?

Comment: edgesForExtendedLayout was set to true, and setting it to false fixed it. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a view above the tableview. Don't know why, it's like an xcode problem i think, check in your document outline in the storyboard if the navigation bar or top bar is above the tableview